# How do I display a greyed out next_post_link when there is no next post

Tags: theme-development, navigation, next-post-link, previous-post-link

Wordpress hides the next and previous post links if there are none, but for the sake of visual consistency I'd like to serve up a greyed out version of the link when there is no next or previous post.

I'm assuming a simple if else statement will do, but I don't really do PHP.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that there's not really an easy way to do it.  There is a solution, but it's sort of ugly. (see waay below.)

### A Longer Answer

I'm including this here in the hopes that it's helpful to someone.

Whenever you happen to be using a built in WordPress function, it's instructive to actually go look at what the function does.  This is especially true if you wish to modify the output.

So let's track down `next_post_link`.  Here's the source of that function from `wp-includes/link-template.php`.

```
<?php
/**                                                                             
 * Display next post link that is adjacent to the current post.                 
 *                                                                              
 * @since 1.5.0                                                                 
 *                                                                              
 * @param string $format Optional. Link anchor format.                          
 * @param string $link Optional. Link permalink format.                         
 * @param bool $in_same_cat Optional. Whether link should be in a same category.
 * @param array|string $excluded_categories Optional. Array or comma-separated list of excluded category IDs.
 */                                                                             
function next_post_link($format='%link &raquo;', $link='%title', $in_same_cat = false, $excluded_categories = '') {
    adjacent_post_link($format, $link, $in_same_cat, $excluded_categories, false);
}
```

Not very exciting.  Just a wrapper around another function:

```
<?php
function adjacent_post_link($format, $link, $in_same_cat = false, $excluded_categories = '', $previous = true) {
    if ( $previous && is_attachment() )                                         
        $post = & get_post($GLOBALS['post']->post_parent);                      
    else                                                                        
        $post = get_adjacent_post($in_same_cat, $excluded_categories, $previous);

    if ( !$post )                                                               
        return;                                                                 

    $title = $post->post_title;                                                 

    if ( empty($post->post_title) )                                             
        $title = $previous ? __('Previous Post') : __('Next Post');             

    $title = apply_filters('the_title', $title, $post->ID);                     
    $date = mysql2date(get_option('date_format'), $post->post_date);            
    $rel = $previous ? 'prev' : 'next';                                         

    $string = '<a href="'.get_permalink($post).'" rel="'.$rel.'">';             
    $link = str_replace('%title', $title, $link);                               
    $link = str_replace('%date', $date, $link);                                 
    $link = $string . $link . '</a>';                                           

    $format = str_replace('%link', $link, $format);                             

    $adjacent = $previous ? 'previous' : 'next';                                
    echo apply_filters( "{$adjacent}_post_link", $format, $link );              
}
```

The trouble spot is here:

```
<?php                                                                            
if ( $previous && is_attachment() )                                         
    $post = & get_post($GLOBALS['post']->post_parent);                      
else                                                                        
    $post = get_adjacent_post($in_same_cat, $excluded_categories, $previous);

if ( !$post )                                                               
    return;
```

If there's not a next post (what `get_adjacent_post` does), the function just returns -- bypassing any filters we may want to hook into. Sucks.

### A Hackish PHP Solution

Create a wrapper around `next_post_link` in your theme's `functions.php` file.  Accept all the same arguments as `next_post_link`.  The only difference is that you're going to start an output buffer before calling `next_post_link`.  Then flush the buffer into a variable -- if the variable is empty, replace it with your placeholder/disabled link.

```
<?php
function wpse53800_next_post_link($format='%link &raquo;', $link='%title', $in_same_cat=false, $exclude_cats='')
{                                                                               
    // start the output buffer                                                  
    ob_start();                                                                 

    // call next_post_link                                                      
    next_post_link($format, $link, $in_same_cat, $exclude_cats);                

    // flush the output buffer into $rv                                         
    $rv = ob_get_flush();                                                       

    // if there's nothing in the buffer, you can add it                         
    if(!$rv)                                                                    
    {                                                                           
        $rv = 'replace this with disabled link';                                
    }                                                                           
    echo $rv;                                                                   
}
```

### An Equally Hackish JavaScript (jQuery) Solution

Somewhere in your theme's JS file(s), you can select the next post link container and add a placeholder if there isn't anything.

An example for TwentyEleven:

```
<script type="text/javascript">                                                 
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {                                         
        var n = jQuery('span.nav-next');                                        
        if(n.length && n.html() == '') {                                        
            n.html('replace this with disabled link');                          
        }                                                                       
    });                                                                         
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a link to the previous or next post, you can replace the missing link with any html content.

```
    function posts_pagination_output( $template, $class ) {

        $prev = get_previous_post_link();
        $next = get_next_post_link();
        if($prev == ''){$prev = '<span>No previous post.</span>';}else{$prev = '';}
        if($next == ''){$next = '<span>No next post.</span>';}else{$next = '';}

        $template = '
        <nav class="navigation %1$s" role="navigation" aria-label="%4$s">
        <h2 class="screen-reader-text">%2$s</h2>
        <div class="nav-links d-flex justify-content-between py-3">'.$prev.'%3$s'.$next.'</div>
        </nav>';

        return $template;
    }
    add_filter( 'navigation_markup_template', 'posts_pagination_output', 99, 2 );
```